# Heavy Disk I/O in Background Thread Locks UI

Tags: .net, multithreading, backgroundworker, async-await

I'm getting heavy disk I/O during a `SqlCeEngine.Upgrade()` call against a 230MB database--as expected.

The problem is that even though it's running in a `BackgroundWorker` thread, it still locks up the UI. I've tried `Async/Await` to no avail. (FWIW, I'll be upgrading the code as time allows.)

I'm pulling my hair out with this. I need to show an indeterminate progress bar as this runs, yet it freezes halfway through no matter what I do. The only solution I can think of is to do the upgrade in a completely separate process, which of course is pretty kludgy. If I have to I will, though.

Excerpted code is below.

Any ideas?

```
Friend Class MainForm
  Private Sub itmRestore_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles itmRestore.Click
    If Utils.MsgQuestion(Bl.Messages.DB_RESTORE_PROMPT) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
      ofdRestore.InitialDirectory = Bl.Registry.DownloadFolder
      ofdRestore.FileName = String.Empty

      If ofdRestore.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        prgCopy.SourcePath = ofdRestore.FileName
        prgCopy.TargetPath = Db.Utils.DatabasePath
        prgCopy.ActionText = "Restoring the database..."

        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        bgwBackup.RunWorkerAsync(Bl.BackgroundJobs.RestoreDatabase)
      End If
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub bgwBackup_DoWork(Sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwBackup.DoWork
    bgwStartup.ReportProgress(-1, "Loading...")

    Select Case DirectCast(e.Argument, Bl.BackgroundJobs)
      Case Bl.BackgroundJobs.BackupDatabase : Bl.Jobs.Database.BackupDatabase(prgCopy, e)
      Case Bl.BackgroundJobs.RestoreDatabase : Bl.Jobs.Database.RestoreDatabase(prgCopy, e)
      Case Bl.BackgroundJobs.CheckDatabaseVersion : Bl.Jobs.Database.CheckDatabaseVersion(e)
      Case Bl.BackgroundJobs.UpgradeDatabase : Bl.Jobs.Database.UpgradeDatabase(e)
      Case Bl.BackgroundJobs.UpdateDatabaseSchema : Bl.Jobs.Database.UpdateDatabaseSchema(Sender, e)
    End Select
  End Sub

  Private Sub bgwBackup_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgwBackup.ProgressChanged
    UpdateProgress(e.ProgressPercentage, e.UserState)
  End Sub

  Private Sub bgwBackup_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgwBackup.RunWorkerCompleted
    Dim eNextJob As Bl.BackgroundJobs
    Dim oManager As Bl.Jobs.Manager

    oManager = e.Result

    If e.Error Is Nothing Then
      Select Case oManager.CurrentJob
        Case Bl.BackgroundJobs.BackupDatabase
          eNextJob = Bl.BackgroundJobs.None
          UpdateProgress(0)
          Utils.MsgInformation(Bl.Messages.DB_BACKUP_SUCCESS.ToFormat(vbCrLf, sfdBackup.FileName))

        Case Bl.BackgroundJobs.RestoreDatabase
          eNextJob = Bl.BackgroundJobs.CheckDatabaseVersion
          UpdateProgress(0)
          Utils.MsgInformation(Bl.Messages.DB_RESTORE_SUCCESS)

        Case Bl.BackgroundJobs.CheckDatabaseVersion
          If oManager.Continue Then
            eNextJob = Bl.BackgroundJobs.UpdateDatabaseSchema
          Else
            eNextJob = Bl.BackgroundJobs.UpgradeDatabase
            Utils.MsgInformation(Bl.Messages.DB_UPGRADE_NOTICE)
            UpdateProgress(-1, "Upgrading the database...")
          End If

        Case Bl.BackgroundJobs.UpgradeDatabase
          eNextJob = Bl.BackgroundJobs.UpdateDatabaseSchema
          UpdateProgress(0)
          Utils.MsgInformation(Bl.Messages.DB_UPGRADE_SUCCESS)

        Case Bl.BackgroundJobs.UpdateDatabaseSchema
          eNextJob = Bl.BackgroundJobs.None

      End Select
    Else
      Utils.MsgCritical(Bl.Messages.DB_RESTORE_ERROR.ToFormat(vbCrLf, e.Error.ToString))
      eNextJob = Bl.BackgroundJobs.None
    End If

    If eNextJob = Bl.BackgroundJobs.None Then
      UpdateProgress(0, "Ready")
      txtLastName.Focus()

      Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    Else
      bgwBackup.RunWorkerAsync(eNextJob)
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub UpdateProgress(ProgressPercentage As Integer)
    UpdateProgress(ProgressPercentage, String.Empty)
  End Sub

  Private Sub UpdateProgress(ProgressPercentage As Integer, StatusText As String)
    If ProgressPercentage = -1 Then
      If prgProgress.Style <> ProgressBarStyle.Marquee Then
        prgProgress.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
        prgProgress.Value = 0
      End If
    Else
      prgProgress.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks
      prgProgress.Value = Min(ProgressPercentage, 100)
    End If

    If Trim(StatusText).Length > 0 Then
      lblStatus.Text = StatusText
    End If
  End Sub

End Class

Namespace Bl
  Namespace Jobs
    Friend Class Manager
      Public CurrentJob As BackgroundJobs
      Public [Continue] As Boolean

      Public Sub New(CurrentJob As BackgroundJobs, [Continue] As Boolean)
        Me.CurrentJob = CurrentJob
        Me.Continue = [Continue]
      End Sub
    End Class

    Friend Class Database
      Public Shared Sub CheckDatabaseVersion(e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        e.Result = New Manager(e.Argument, Db.Utils.CheckDatabaseVersion)
      End Sub

      Public Shared Sub UpgradeDatabase(e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Db.Utils.UpgradeDatabase()
        e.Result = New Manager(e.Argument, True)
      End Sub

      Public Shared Sub UpdateDatabaseSchema(Worker As BackgroundWorker, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        If Db.Versioning.SchemaVersionStatus = Db.Enums.SchemaVersionStates.Newer Then
          Throw New ApplicationException("An incompatible database version has been detected. A newer version of Matrix is required.")
        Else
          Db.Versioning.UpdateSchema(Worker, e)
          e.Result = New Manager(e.Argument, True)
        End If
      End Sub

      Public Shared Sub BackupDatabase(Copier As ProgressCopy.ProgressCopy, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Copier.Start()
        e.Result = New Manager(e.Argument, True)
      End Sub

      Public Shared Sub RestoreDatabase(Copier As ProgressCopy.ProgressCopy, e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        Db.Utils.ArchiveDatabase()
        Copier.Start()
        e.Result = New Manager(e.Argument, True)
      End Sub
    End Class
  End Namespace

  Friend Enum BackgroundJobs
    None
    UpgradeDatabase
    UpdateDatabaseSchema
    ValidateCityCode
    CheckSubscription
    CheckOptionsWizard
    CheckDatabaseVersion
    BackupDatabase
    RestoreDatabase
  End Enum
End Namespace

Namespace Db
  Friend Class Utils
    Public Shared Sub UpgradeDatabase()
      Dim _
        sSource,
        sTarget As String

      sSource = ArchiveDatabase()
      sTarget = DatabasePath

      Try
        With New SqlCeEngine(SqlCe.Connection.ConnectionString(sSource))
          .Upgrade(SqlCe.Connection.ConnectionString(sTarget))
        End With

      Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New ApplicationException(ex.Message, ex)

      End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ArchiveDatabase() As String
      Dim oFile As FileInfo

      Dim _
        sTarget,
        sNow As String

      Dim _
          oSource, _
          oTarget _
        As DirectoryInfo

      Do
        sNow = Now.ToFileNameString(DateStringOptions.IncludeTime)
        oSource = New DirectoryInfo(DatabaseFolder)
        sTarget = Path.Combine(oSource.FullName, "Deleted {0}".ToFormat(sNow))
        oTarget = New DirectoryInfo(sTarget)
      Loop While oTarget.Exists

      oTarget.Create()

      For Each oFile In oSource.GetFiles
        oFile.MoveTo(Path.Combine(oTarget.FullName, oFile.Name))
      Next

      ArchiveDatabase = Path.Combine(oTarget.FullName, Db.Utils.DatabaseFile)
    End Function
  End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: `Async`/`Await`, by themselves actually try to keep processing happening in the same context. They're not a means (in themselves) of moving work off onto other threads. The obvious thing is that *something* is forcing its way back onto the UI thread and then blocking. Without seeing some code, it's going to be nigh on impossible to guess what that thing is.

Comment: You're right -- some sample code is in order. I've edited my original message. It's pretty simple, really, which is what's so odd about it.

Comment: It is hard to say what's wrong from the code; try replacing all db access with `Thread.Sleep` and see what happens. It's possible you may be sending progress updates to the UI thread too quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the backgroundworker wrong. From [`DoWork`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in your `DoWork` event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) events.

It sure looks like you're manipulating the UI from your `DoWork` handler.

Comment: Good catch. In the sample code, you're right. It's pseudo-code. In the real code I'm using the ProgressChanged event. I just forgot about that while putting the sample together, that's all.

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever I neglected to address the previous comment directly to you--here's the notice for you.

Comment: @InteXX - you don't have to `@` if you're directing a message to the author of the parent post (answer or question) - they get notified of all comments added. If it's not the real code, it's again difficult to help you diagnose the issue.

Comment: Got it, thanks. OK, here's a code update. I'm trying to keep it small for ease of analysis. This is still only an excerpt with several missing dependencies, but the pertinent structure is here. The real item is huge. If you want the whole thing I can do it, but are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick with BackgroundWorker for the moment, where it's 100% clear that the upgrade is running on a separate pool thread.

Then I'd investigate exactly what the foreground is trying to do at the point it hangs.  You might consider using [ProcDump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) for this.

My guess would be that the foreground is, at some point, making some call into the database layer which then blocks because the upgrade is running.  Don't forget that this call could be as a result of pretty much anything (timer, mouse movement whatever), but that once it has blocked it will stall the whole message pump, which will then hang the UI.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try ProcDump tomorrow and report back here.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it yet, but when I do I'll update this page. Thanks again for the pointer.